# Cannot find name 'options'? Do I need to declare before?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I'm trying to pick a image from the gallery using this function:

```
getImg(){

    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
      }
    }, (err) => { });
  }
```

But I'm getting this error: `Cannot find name 'options'`, If I declate as:

```
declare let options: any;
```

the error goes away but the Button doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` is an object of `ImagePickerOptions`. It can have any of the below options:

1. maximumImagesCount
2. width
3. Height
4. quality
5. outputType

Source: [Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker/)

Image Picker Example: [Example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-implement-image-picker-in-ionic-application-using-cordova-and-native-plugin/#more-1896)

Try this below code.

```
    getImages() {
    this.options = {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      quality: 25,
      outputType: 1
    };
    this.imageResponse = [];
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.options).then((results) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        this.imageResponse.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + results[i]);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      alert(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Since i'm already injecting here:  `private options: ImagePickerOptions` , do I need to do before?

Comment: With your code I still get  cannot find name 'options'.

Comment: You have to declare that 'options' variable in your class globally before the constructor or you can declare that 'options' variable as a locally in your `getImage()` method and use that 'options' variable without `this`. You can declare local variable in your method using `let` keyword. Like `let options:ImagePickerOptions;` @rzp

Comment: Yes, It was exactly it. Thanks for the response Guys !

Answer (score 0):

You can declare options like this :
`var options = {
   maximumImagesCount: 10,
   width: 800,
   height: 800,
   quality: 80
  };`